# React Native + Redux Orm Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect (screenshot)

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

I have came across multiple threads about this but failed to find a solution. Most of them are for web apps. I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thx for looking.

[I have created a repo for my code.](https://github.com/ODelibalta/rnativeRNFWixNativeNavReduxOrm)

#### package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "native-base": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.134",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-orm": "^0.9.4",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-orm-proptypes": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "verbose": true,
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "__tests__/factories",
      "__tests__/utils"
    ]
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `src/main.js`, your initial render of `<Provider>` is called with the default `this.state.store` set by the constructor, which is `null`.

Instead, create the store and pass it to your `<Root>` component as a prop so it always has a value. Or create the store in the constructor (less nice, but will work)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately, I do not understand. Sorry. I have `setState` in the `componentDidMount()` function of `main.js` which calls the `setup` function in my `store/setup.js` so I am still at lost with your answer. If it helps, it is [mostly from this repo](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-examples/tree/master/src). I appreciate your answer. Thank you

Comment: `componentDidMount` fires after the initial render. See the React Lifecycle https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html